# Wrong evaluation of integral in Mathematica? Numerical vs symbolic

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, code-review

I have *Mathematica* 11.0.1 in Ubuntu 16.04. My problem is that I have an integral but *Mathematica* is evaluating it wrong.
Here is the integral:

```
 Chop[(1/T)*Integrate[Exp[-I*3*ω*t]*(β Cos[ω t]^2) Exp[I*1*ω*t], {t, 0, T}]]
```

Using basic ideas($\frac{1}{4} e^{-2 i \pi\omega  t}+\frac{1}{4} e^{2 i \pi \omega t}+\frac{1}{2}$), it is clear that the integral should be $\beta/4$. But *Mathematica* gives this result:

```
0.195312 β
```

Ingredients:
(i) Choose $T=0.01$, $\omega = 2\pi/T$.

**Addendum**:
(i) Where am I going wrong?
    Why such anomaly is coming?
(I really would like to know this. I think most of the time I know how to use *Mathematica* but then such wondrous things happen, and then again I am inside a Shutter Island(start again).)

(ii) If I choose $T=0.1$, answer is zero.

(iii) Variables($T$, $\omega$) are need to be declared or defined *Globally*, as they are required at so many places in my code(this was just an example). If I have to change the value then it has to be done at one place(globally defined), not locally at each defining places(cumbersome).

(iv) Finally, I have this

```
HB[a_, b_, t_, 
   k_] := {{0, -($q[a, t] + $w[b, t]*Exp[I k a])}, {-($q[a, t] + 
       $w[b, t]*Exp[-I k a]), 0}};
where,  $q[a, t] = a*Cos[ω t]^2, and $w = b
```

instead of `(β Cos[ω t]^2)` in the integrand.

(V) ***Speed is the only problem in the received answer(thanks a lot for the answer, though), if there is any idea which can be used by optimizing the code and decreasing the computation time, it will be a great help. Instead of 3 and 1 in exponential, I have $i$ and $j$ inside a Table, forming a square matrix, that is where the code received in answer was very slow. ***

```
ParallelTable[AbIntHB[a, b, i, j, k], {i, 0, 21}, {j, 0, 21}];
```

where `AbIntHB[a, b, i, j, k]` = Above Integral with `HB` matrix in between the `Exponentials` with `i`->`Exp[-I*i*ω*t]` and `j`->`Exp[I*j*ω*t]` indices.

Comment: restart your kernel? I get `Chop[(1/T)*
   Integrate[
    Exp[-I*3*\[Omega]*t]*(\[Beta] Cos[\[Omega] t]^2) Exp[
      I*1*\[Omega]*t], {t, 0, T}] /. {T -> .01, \[Omega] -> 
    2 Pi /.01}]` --> `0.25 beta`

Comment: @Feyre It is working but for my program it is necessary to define the variables(`T`) Globally not locally. Please see the addendum(ii) and (iii), again due to global assigning

Comment: You need to use rational constants.
`T = 1/100; \[Omega] = 
 100 2 Pi; Chop[(1/T) Evaluate[ 
   Integrate[
    Exp[-I 3 \[Omega] t]*(\[Beta] Cos[\[Omega] t]^2) Exp[
      I \[Omega] t], {t, 0, T}]]]`.

Comment: how 'a' and 'b' are defined?

Comment: @Stitch just real variables

Comment: so, if you use your new equation, you get the result as a function of all of those, right?

Comment: @Stitch, yes precisely

Comment: edited the answer to include it

Comment: I will suggest numerically integrating, after specific values are given, pulling out the "beta" constant" first. Could be done as follows. `int[tT_?NumericQ, w_?NumericQ] := 
 Re[1/tT*NIntegrate[
    Exp[-I*3*w*t]*( Cos[w*t]^2) Exp[I*1*w*t], {t, 0, tT}]]
In[1507]:= Timing[int[.01, 2*Pi/.01]]
Out[1507]= {0.024432, 0.25}`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks for your input, instead of `3` and `1` in exponential, I have `i` and `j`(inside a `Table`, forming a square matrix, that is where the code received in answer was very slow). Can I use `i` and `j` as `int[tT_?NumericQ, w_?NumericQ, i_?NumericQ ,j_?NumericQ ] :=...`

Comment: Yes, I would suggest adding the exponents to the input in that way (or could restrict to integers if you like, as in `i_Integer`...).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I tried this(thanks for it) but when I entered `( Cos[w*t]^3)` instead of`( Cos[w*t]^2)`, the error `NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in t near {t} ={0.0099999998206481786100171446606970399010477258683327050903244526125}. NIntegrate obtained -2.1684*10^-19+2.1684*10^-19 I and 2.0345806762755383*^-15 for the integral and error estimates.`It means this code is not general, is there a way to generalize it. I hope you can write in the form of an answer and post here(fast though, only need to make general),complete.

Comment: The code is fine. That warning simply means it is likely to be zero. It's difficult to reach an accuracy goal if the result is zero.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Ooh I see. Is there a way to get out of this error? Defining  something specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`T` and `ω` must be either undefined or exact numbers. If they are defined globally and you don't want to change it, you can do the following:

```
ClearAll[T, ω];
T = 0.01; ω = 2 Pi/T;
Chop[Block[{T = $T, ω = $w}, (1/T)*
    Integrate[
     Exp[-I*3*ω*t]*(β Cos[ω t]^2) Exp[
       I*1*ω*t], {t, 0, T}]] /. {$T -> T, $w -> ω}]
```

> 0.25 β

Using your equations:

```
ClearAll[T, ω];
T = 0.01; ω = 2 Pi/T;
int[a_, b_, t_, k_] :=
 Chop[Block[{T = $T, ω = $w},
    HB = {{0, -(a*Cos[ω t]^2 + 
          b*Exp[I k a])}, {-(a*Cos[ω t]^2 + b*Exp[-I k a]), 0}};
    {{0, -(a*Cos[ω t]^2 + 
         b*Exp[I k a])}, {-(a*Cos[ω t]^2 + b*Exp[-I k a]), 0}};
    (1/T) Integrate[Exp[-I*3*ω*t] HB Exp[I*1*ω*t], {t, 0, T}]] /. {$T -> T, $w -> ω}]

int[-β, 0, t, k]
```

> {{0, 0.25 β}, {0.25 β, 0}}

Comment: Aah thanks. Please see my edit(addendum). I would like to know the problem, why it happened(if it makes sense to ask this).

Comment: The issue here is exact calculation vs. numeric approximation. Related [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38457/44141)

Comment: Good one. Is there a way to speed it up. as insteas of 3 and 1 in exponential, I have `i and j` and it is now very slow(for evaluating all of them).

Comment: Probably you can optimize the assignment of variables, but the integration takes the most time. Try numeric integration in [parallel](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1620/44141)?

Comment: Just a last and most essential query, can we use `Module` instead of `Block`. Will it still work?

Comment: I was telling you about the speed of the calculation. When I accept those garbage result(mentioned in my question), it is very fast. But after `Block` it is insanely slow. That really surprised me, now I am trying to find other way to the result you got(in my case or every case, computation speed matters a lot). If you come up with other idea, please let me know.

Comment: Not sure I get the same results though. Using Block for the simple case `Chop[Block[{T = $T, \[Omega] = $w}, (1/T)*Integrate[Exp[-I*3*\[Omega]*t]*(\[Beta] Cos[\[Omega] t]^2) Exp[I*1*\[Omega]*t], {t, 0, T}]] /. {$T -> T, $w -> \[Omega]}] // RepeatedTiming` gets you 0.019 s and the correct result, while your original code is 0.027 s with an incorrect one. And the same is about the full version.

Comment: For the time being I am just waiting for the new answers, where the speed can be reduced, I am sorry for this.