# Fourier Transform(first use)

Tags: fourier-analysis, code-review, code-request

This is in continuation of the question I asked [Wrong evaluation of integral in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/137087/wrong-evaluation-of-integral-in-mathematica) But I will try to make it self contained.

I have a periodic function `funct[h_,t_] = Cos[ω*t]^2`(where `ω` will be removed if calculating using `Fourier Transform` but not while using integral just below, shown below). I need to evaluate an integral of this form `Integrate[Exp[-I*m*ω*t]Mytest[h, t]Exp[I*n*ω*t],{t,0,2π/ω}]` where $ω=100.0$.

Then this quantity,

```
funct[h_, t_] := h Cos[ω*t]^2; 

Mytest[h_, t_] := {{0, -funct[h, t]}, {-funct[h, t], 0}};

ParallelTable[Integrate[Exp[-I*m*ω*t]Mytest[h, t]Exp[I*n*ω*t],{t,0,2π/ω}],{m,0,len},{n,0,len}]
```

So, I come up with my own idea to calculate this *numercially* after searching a lot, i.e. by using the `Fourier Transform` invoking the `FourierSeries` package in *Mathematica 11*. Where I need not have to calculate this integral explicitly and it will save my time. But it didn't work.

Here is the program

```
In[11]:= << FourierSeries`

In[12]:=

ClearAll;
    len = 2;

(*This is a variable periodic function, can change to different periodic function*)
    funct[h_, t_] := h Cos[t]^2; 

    Mytest[h_, t_] := {{0, -funct[h, t]}, {-funct[h, t], 0}}; 

    Mresult[h_, n_, m_] := FourierTransform[Mytest[h, t]/π, t, n + m, 
      FourierParameters -> {1, -1}];

    Mresult[h, n, m]

    HND[h_] = 
      ParallelTable[Mresult[h, n, m], {n, 0, 2 len}, {m, 0, 2 len}];

    Out[12]= {{0, -(1/2) h DiracDelta[-2 + m + n] - h DiracDelta[m + n] - 
       1/2 h DiracDelta[2 + m + n]}, {-(1/2) h DiracDelta[-2 + m + n] - 
       h DiracDelta[m + n] - 1/2 h DiracDelta[2 + m + n], 0}}
```

I did it and as per the function and checking the surviving component, i.e. $h\cos^{2}(t)=h(\frac{1}{4} e^{-2 i t}+\frac{1}{4} e^{2 i t}+\frac{1}{2})$, using this, the result should be (numerically it should be `0.5h` instead of `h/2`)

```
  {{-h, 0, -h/2, 0, 0},
  {0, -h, 0, -h/2, 0},
  {-h/2, 0, -h, 0, -h/2},
  {0, -h/2, 0, -h, 0},
  {0, 0, -h/2, 0, -h}}
```

Instead of this what I got.
[image]
Any input in the right direction will be highly appreciable. I am still new to Mathematica and its workings, even its interpretation of different functions(here `Dirac Delta`).

Is there an another we of seeing or solving this, even a hint will be more than enough(may more than that, if needed)?

***(As I am low on reputation, I have to think many times to put some bounty on this, and get your attention. Forgive me for this and please give your attention.)***

Comment: Do you want the `FourierTransform` or the `FourierSeries`?

Comment: @Pillsy I just want evaluation of this `ParallelTable[Integrate[Exp[-I*m*ω*t]Mytest[h, t]Exp[I*n*ω*t],{t,0,2π/ω}],{m,0,len},{n,0,len}]`. So, I saw `Fourier Transform` close to this, and used it. Sorry, no further ideas.

Comment: When I do that, it just works? The dimensions aren't quite what you're looking for, but the step where the `Integrate` happens is fine.

Comment: @Pillsy My main aim is to collect the surviving terms(for present function, after putting them inside the matrix they should look like as in the matrix at the bottom of the post). I was using `Dirac Delta` to put the surviving terms analogous to `Kronecker Delta`. But didn't work, though.